# Can't load specific Roboto font

Tags: css, fonts, roboto

My problem is very simple and the symptom is weird.

In the head of my HTML, I have included the code to load the font directly from Google Font.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.text {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            font-size: large;
        }
```

No matter what customization I choose, the font seems to be the normal font. I tried with Roboto Thin (Roboto:100) and Roboto Thin Italic (Roboto:100i) but none of them actually change.

Is there anything that I miss in my code?

Comment: Have you tried to change your `font-weight` property? (e.g. to 300 or 400 or 700)

Comment: @exoslav no I haven't. The documentation on Google doesn't mention anything about font weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which font you have from google, in this case:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

You approach to each font weight in CSS like that:

```
// 300 weight
.text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

// 400 weight
.text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

// 700 weight
.text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: You have `font-size` in your examples. Did you mean to use `font-weight`?

Comment: Yes, definitely, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You are loading Roboto font with 700 font weight and trying to show it with 100 font weight. Embed it with the following URL:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Using this link, it will work fine for you.

Update: This code snippet will explain you it in detail.

```css
.text  {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}
.text-100 {
    font-weight: 100;
}
.text-100i {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;
}
.text-400 {
    font-weight: 400;
}
.text-700 {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,400,700" rel="stylesheet"> 

<div class="text text-100">
Hello (Font weight: 100)
</div>
    
<div class="text text-100i">
Hello (Font weight: 100i)
</div>
    
<div class="text text-400">
Hello (Font weight: 400) 
</div>
    
<div class="text text-700">
Hello (Font weight: 700)
</div>
```

Comment: I tried putting 100 and 100i already but nothing happened. I switch to 700 to see if there is anything change. But nothing.

Comment: Can you explain more why you load so many different customization? And how can the browser know which one to display?

Comment: I have added the code snippet in my answer to explain it to you better.

Comment: You can load just one font weight whichever you need. I added multiple of them to explain it to you

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to set the font of your weight in your CSS

```
.text { 
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Is this a must? I thought that if I load only that font, that will be the only 'Roboto' font that I have?

Comment: The browser still 'creates' a non-bold version of the font, so if you're only wanting to load in the bold font then yeah, this will be necessary. I would advise that you either load in the lighter fonts too, or include font weights

Answer (score 1):

First of all load all the fonts-
 
Just use

> **font-weight: 100|300|700** /*Any one of them*/ .

Google fonts basically work with **font-weight** property. The google fonts are rendered according to the font weight specifications. 
For example-

```
Case 1 - font-weight:100 then thin font will load.

Case 2 - font-weight:300 then light font will load.

Case 3 - font-weight:700 then bold font will load.
```

Comment: Google's documentation doesn't mention this. Can you show me where to read about this?

Answer (score 1):

In your css file, add:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700');
```

at the top.

And, user it in the desired class like:

```
.class{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```